# Angular 6 - Binding item not updating after data change

Tags: angular, api, data-binding

In my HTML I am binding an item in a repeat:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item in items">
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
</ul>
```

This is working fine.  But now that value is being changed in an API call, like so:

```
doApiCall(){
    let value = this.items.find( x => x.id = '123');
    this.service.doIt().subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<myModel>) => {
            // response === { id = 456' }
            return value = res.body;
        }
    )
}
```

now the item in the array has changed, but the view does not change.  But the funny thing is, if I change the `let value` manually right after it is set, like so:

```
let value = this.items.find( x => x.id = '123');
value.id = '345'
```

then the update happens.  So I do not know If I am doing something wrong in the API call.

Comment: Just FYI `{{ item.id }}` is a 1-way binding. 2-way bindings are used with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @JonasPraem Silly me, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @JonasPraem What? How you want to make 2-way binding on template without `<input>`?

Comment: @web.dev Unrelated to OP's issue. But would you want a 2-way binding anywhere else than where the user can change the value? I was referring to OP's title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you need to refresh how JavaScript works. You are returning `value = res.body` value. But what's that? That won't even work.

It seems like `items` is array of objects which are reference types. When you are trying to do `value = res.body` you are not changing anything inside `items` array at all. You are just reassigning reference which is stored in `value` variable, but your item found with `Array.find` function is untouched. Maybe you should try doing something like

```
doApiCall() {
    let value = this.items.find(x => x.id = '123');
    this.service.doIt().subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse < any > ) => {
            value.id = res.body.id;
            value.someproperty = res.body.property;
        }
    )
}
```

But I don't know your `HttpResponse.body` model. That's why you should response `Promise<T>` from service instead of `HttpResponse<any>`. You are using TypeScript, so make it useful!

Comment: Thanks, my HttpResponse actually has a model.  Sorry, my mistake, should have clarified.  But individually assigning my values solved the issue.  Thank you.  But why is my object a `reference` inside the method but the values are not

Comment: Okay, let's say that you have two models:

ModelA {
 property1: number;
 property2: number;
 property3: ModelB;
}

ModelB {
 property1: string;
 property2: number;
}

If you are storing array of ModelA, you are storing references to ModelA object. Then if you use `array.find` to get ModelA, now you can access: ModelA.property1 - value type. ModelA.property2 - value type. ModelA.property3 - reference type. ModelA.property3.property1 - value type.

You need to know which types are references and which are values. In simple words, every object is reference type.

Comment: That's core concept of programming. Just type "reference vs value type JavaScript" in DuckDuck or Google, you will find something.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much for the support!